# Can I throw away the Potted Piranha Plant?

Tags: mario-kart-8

Often times I'll be racing and the game will give me the Piranha Plant.  This item seems to be a timed item which will be used up after a certain number of seconds.  I often want to ditch the item before the next series of ? boxes.  Is there a way of doing so?

Is there any way to drop the Piranha Plant in Mario-Kart 8 (even if you must do so before using the item)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sadly. The only way to get rid of it would be to be hit by an attack that makes you drop items, like Lightning.

Comment: Such a shame.  I hate getting that power up as it often prevents me from getting the next power up.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to drop it, but you can time it so that it ends just before the next (second) series of items.

If your powerup ends right after passing a series of items, you risk being hit by everyone behind you.